# how send email with attachements in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying out following code for send email with attachemnts.
however this code sends only email not attachements.

can someone please help ?

```
open(SENDMAIL, "|/usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t -i") or die "Can't fork for sendmail: $!\n";

print SENDMAIL <<"EOF";

From: <new\@something.com>

To: <new\@something.com>

Cc: <new\@something.com>

Subject: this is our email

Content-type: text/plain

Hi This is the mail

EOF

close(SENDMAIL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sending email from Perl using raw Unix commands like that went out of fashion about twenty years ago. You'd be far better off looking for a good CPAN module.

In this case, I'd recommend [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).

```
Email::Stuffer->from('new@something.com')
              ->to('new@something.com')
              ->cc('new@something.com')
              ->subject('this is our email')
              ->text_body('Hi, this is the email')
              ->attach_file('your_file.txt')
              ->send;
```

Not using CPAN is just making your life harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

mailx - is the solution here.
`echo "Reminder " | mailx -asm\@pe.net -a "location of file" -s "this is email" -asm\@pe.net`